# Docker: Is there a way to resolve the tags of the layer digests?

Tags: docker, tags, digest

I want to check, which FROM docker layers where used.

If you execute `docker inspect` you get the sha digest. But how can I resolve the digest into the docker labels? Especially, if I don't know, how the base docker images were build?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

There's no trivial way to do this because a tag is a many to one pointer to an image, and the build resolves the tag reference to an image. Once you've taken that step from tag to image, you can't easily go back since there can be multiple tags all pointing to that one image. You can resolve potential tags by comparing the layers with other images you've pulled, but that's an unreliable method for images built on other hosts.